# pyhs2 - execute finish but doesn't return

Tags: python, hive

I'm an italian developer and this is my first message here, so sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

This is my problem with pyhs2 module:
I successfully build a connection to my hive database using pyhs2.connect method, and everything works right; the problem is that the same query sometimes freeze, depending on the width of the 'date' clause I use in my query.

Let me explain: if I run cur.execute method with the same query, first with the clause

```
(date >= '2017-03-01' and date <= '2017-05-10')
```

then with the clause

```
(date >= '2017-03-01' and date <= '2017-05-11')
```

(or even without the 'date' clause)

the first occurrence works right and return the correct results while the second (or third) stay freeze until I manually stop the script.

This behavior is very weird for me because I know there are some data after the 05-10, also I can check my database's running applications and, after my second query successfully ends, it stay pending in running applications for a while, and even when it's done, python script stay in a 'freezed state' and never return the correct results.

I think it might be a timeout problem or something like that, but I've searched both here in your useful website and on the web in general for some solutions, but found nothing.

I don't know if it could be an hive problem (for example for the TEZ type of its applications) or something from pyhs2, that after a certain amount of time maybe can't be able to retrieve the results from a query, so I ask for your help.

Thanks in advance,
Luca

Comment: After more tests, I can assume that it was, and unfortunately it is, a timeout problem, because I tested the same query with a 2-month period in my 'date' clause, and it returned the correct results, instead a 1-month one in which it was frozen like before.

I think it's very likely that there's a hidden timeout parameter in the connection between python and hive so, when a query takes too long time, python lost its connection and doesn't retrieve any result even when it's done.

May someone could confirm this theory and propose solutions?

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me?